# How to share different picture per platform in Activity View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, message, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am making an app using native Swift where a user can share pre made images using an Activity View Controller (AVC). The images are pretty high resolution at 1024x1024 but when these are forwarded to "Messages" on iOS7 the tops and bottoms get cut off. This does happen when the image is 128x128 or if sharing any resolution on iOS8.

Since I feed the image in as PNGDataRepresentation before showing the AVC I was wondering if there is a way to feed in a different image based on what platform the user selected. I'd basically point to a lower resolution asset if the user selects Messages vs high resolution if selecting Save or Facebook share.

```
func openShareWidget ()
{

    var activityProvider: ShareActivityProvider = ShareActivityProvider();
    activityProvider.currentType = self.currentType;

    var imageData : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedCell.getSharingImage());
    var activityItems : NSArray = [activityProvider, imageData];

    var activityController : SharingActivityViewController = SharingActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: []);

    presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

My ActivityProvider extension implementation below:

```
class ShareActivityProvider: UIActivityItemProvider, UIActivityItemSource {

var currentType : ImageType!;

override func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject?
{
    switch activityType
    {
        case UIActivityTypeMail:
            return "" ;
        case UIActivityTypeMessage:
            return "";
        case UIActivityTypePostToFacebook:
            return "Facebook"
        case UIActivityTypePostToTwitter:
            return "Twitter";
        default:
            return "";
    }
}

override func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject
{
    return "";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this to work by using multiple UIActivityItem providers. One supplies the text for the message body whereas the 2nd supplies the image itself.

```
func openShareWidget ()
{

    var textProvider : ShareTextActivityProvider = ShareTextActivityProvider(); // same as ShareActivityProvider from question       
    var imgProvider : ShareImageActivityProvider = ShareImageActivityProvider()

    var activityItems : NSArray = [textProvider, imgProvider];

    var activityController : SharingActivityViewController = SharingActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: []);

    presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

And here's the ShareImageActivityProvider

```
class ShareImageActivityProvider: UIActivityItemProvider {

var selectedCell : ImageCell!;

override func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject?
{
    return UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedCell.getSharingImage(activityType)); 
}

override func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject
{
    return "";
}

}
```

GetSharingImage:

```
func getSharingImage(activityType : String) -> UIImage
  {
    switch activityType
        {
        case UIActivityTypeMessage:
            return UIImage(named: imgPathLOW);
        case UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter:
            return UIImage(named: imgPathHD);
        default:
            return UIImage(named: "Tex_Empty");
    }
}
```